# Getting module instead of image in VS-code

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

When I tried to get an image or importing an image it is showing like this is a module or alias and it gives the string to me how can I figure it out....???

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a problem. It is always showing the location string as a `module` because that's is the location of some *module* you want to import. In this case it is just a image but in other cases it can be libraries, components, React Hooks etc.

And about the `logo` being of type `string` that's also normal. `logo` is the **source** of the image, and in your `<img />` you have the `src` attribute which accept a **string** value, and that's where the `logo` should be putted.

This is how you use the imoprted `logo` in React:

```
<img src={logo}/> //src accepts string value.
```

Comment: thanks for your help but now it is done

Comment: Well you're welcome. If this answer was useful to you then it would be nice of you to mark it as accepted. Thank you!